# Swift - How to set the image of a UIBarButtonItem in a custom class

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

Hi I have a custom class for a UIBarButtonImage:

```
class CheckBoxBarButton : UIBarButtonItem {

    // images
    let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "img_checked")! as UIImage
    let unCheckedImage = UIImage(named: "img_unchecked")! as UIImage

    //bool property
    var isChecked: Bool = false {
        didSet{
            if isChecked == true {

                // here I want to set the checked image for my bar button

            }else{

                // here I want to set the unchecked image for my bar button
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {

// here I want to add a target when the button is touched.
// the actual code is returning an error because UIBarButtonImage doesnt not have addtarget
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CheckBoxBarButton.buttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        self.isChecked = false
    }
}
```

> Any clue?

Comment: Why dont you do whatever you need inside didSet?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the `image` property

```
var isChecked: Bool = false {
    didSet{
        if isChecked == true {
            self.image = checkedImage
        }else{
            self.image = unCheckedImage
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a button with your image and set the `customView` of `UIBarButtonItem` as your button:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.setImage(checkedImage )// or button.setImage(unCheckedImage) based on the conditions
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
self.customView = button
```

Or set the `customView` image itself if there is already a button defined:

```
self.customView.setImage(checkedImage )
```